# the comma in the csv text sentence is not readable in the output of python pandas read

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Text data in csv file:

Example1:

```
id,name,address
1,hendro,bandung
```

The result:

```
id name class
1 hendro bandung
```

Example2:

```
id,name,class
1,hendro,"bandung,semarang"
```

The result:

```
id                          name class
1,hendro,"bandung,semarang" NaN  NaN
```

I try with `pandas.read.csv()`:

```py
import pandas as pd
train = pd.read_csv('book1.csv')
train
```

My expectation:
the result for example2 is like this;

```
id name   class
1  hendro bandung,semarang
```

What's wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: 1st it will be pd.read_csv("file.csv")
and it is working just fine and reading the file correctly for me.
if you are still facing the issue just put sep = "," as an additional input while reading.

train =  pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep = ",")

Comment: not working for me @AmitGupta maybe any special rule when i create data in csv ?

Comment: What exactly do you expect the output to look like? It would be great if you could add what you expect to your post.

Comment: hello @BenPap thanks but you can look in the example 2.  that is focus my problem

Comment: So you want to keep all the commas between everything?

Comment: The output I want, please you can look in example2 my expectation in the last section. the result that I hope @BenPap

Comment: when you open your csv in text editor it will look like
 "id,name,class"
"1,hendro,""bandung,semarang"""

that's why quotechar not working it ignores the quotes and whole text

Comment: Is there any way for you to upload the csv somewhere? or can you take a screen shot of it?

Comment: Works as expected for me.

Comment: Update your pandas version perhaps? I tried with `0.24.2` and it works fine.

Comment: @pythonjokeun pandas version same with you

Comment: @Chirag great that's true bro, and success when i change manually in notepad, how we can create automatically data in CSV ? do you have references for me?

Comment: @HendroPrasetyo added an approach please check.

Comment: According to the question the data does not look like that. If the example in the question is wrong you should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below logic for this case.

```
Step 1 : Open your CSV and replace double quotes (") to single Quote (').
Step 2 : Run the below code.

df = pd.read_csv('Workbook1.csv', sep=',',quotechar="'")
print df

# renaming the first and last columns as extra '"' is attached with them
df = df.rename(columns={'"id':'id','class"':'class'})

# remove all the '"' from the data
df = df.applymap(lambda x:str(x).replace('"',""))
print df
```

Output:

```
  "id    name             class"
0  "1  hendro  bandung,semarang"
1  "2   he'sn             hen's"

   id    name             class
0  1  hendro  bandung,semarang
1  2   he'sn             hen's
```

Data looks like below when opened in notepad:

```
"id,name,class"
"1,hendro,'bandung,semarang'"
"2,he'sn,hen's"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following argument to your code:

```
import pandas as pd  
pd.read_csv('book1.csv', quotechar = '"')
```

Comment: Only thing I can think of that might help here is to add:                                        
`pd.read_csv(books1.csv, skipinitialspace = True, quotechar = '"')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('book1.csv', sep=",", names= ['id','Name','From','To'])
df = df.iloc[1:]
df['class'] = df['From'] +','+ df['To']
df = df[['id','Name','class']]
df
```

Comment: not I want, still can't bro. help for another solution

Comment: have you try it?